# Swift - Best way to Save and later get a bunch of Data

Tags: swift, sqlite, tableview, userdefaults

i have the following case to achieve:

I have an UITableView with a List of some Data (Strings), if i tap on a row, i want to see all the Details of the Data. The Data should be added by the User. (TableView Stuff already knowing) i just want to know, how to deal with the save / read stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear but will try to answer. The data that you receive from the user can be saved on server DB via API Calls or can be saved persistently on the device using plist, sqlite, coredata etc... There are multiple ways to save and retrieve the data, checkcout the following tutorial for doing it by Coredata.
https://medium.com/xcblog/core-data-with-swift-4-for-beginners-1fc067cca707